# how to use std::find with an < operator that is not std::less

Tags: c++, stdset

say I have

```
class newVector: public std::vector<T> {
    public:
        bool operator< (const newVector& v) { 
            //..
        }
};
```

And

```
a std::set<newVector>;
```

I can't manage to use a.find(...) properly, I am not sure what to put into the (...) in order to use newVector::operator<. When I just put a.find(element) it uses std::less. Should I change std::less somehow?

Comment: The question I have is why are you deriving from `std::vector`?

Comment: Bad idea to derive from `std::vector` or any standard library class

Comment: I want  to add some things to the std::vector. Someone told me composition is better but this should not be forbidden?

Comment: Umm..yes, it is forbidden (in terms of guidelines). Scott Meyers discusses this in Effective C++

Comment: @myelf Instead of listening to this "someone", research the reasons why deriving from `std::vector` is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring for the time being that deriving from `std::vector` is a bad idea, I can think of the following ways to address the issue:

1. Define `operator<` for objects of `newVector`.

   ```
   class newVector: public std::vector<T> {
       public:
           bool operator< (const newVector& v) const { 
               //..
           }
   ```

   and

   ```
   std::set<newVector> a;
   a.find(...);
   ```
2. Define a functor that has appropriate `operator()` function and use it to create the `std::set`.

   ```
   template <typename T>
   struct NewVectorLess
   {
      bool operator()(newVector<T> const& lhs, newVector<T> const& rhs)
      {
        // ...
      }
   };
   ```

   and

   ```
   std::set<newVector<int>, NewVectorLess<int>> a;
   a.find(...);
   ```

Comment: to be clear this are 2 options? I don't understand the first one I guess there is a const in there but other than that nothing has changed.

Comment: @myelf, Yes. These are two options. In your posted code, you had not only missed the `const` but the argument type is `ImpreciseVector`.

Comment: Oh, that ImperciseVector was an artifact from bad editing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to overload the vector, or to change std::less, but to define separately your own [std::less compatible function object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

    struct OppositeVectorComp
    {
        template< class T, class Alloc >
        bool operator()( const std::vector<T,Alloc>& lhs,const std::vector<T,Alloc>& rhs )
        {           
           return   !(lhs < rhs);
        }
    };

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a , b;

    std::set<std::vector<int>> defaultset;
    std::set<std::vector<int>, OppositeVectorComp> myset;

    a.push_back(1);
    b.push_back(2);

    myset.insert(a);
    myset.insert(b);

    defaultset.insert(a);
    defaultset.insert(b);

    std::cout << (*myset.begin())[0] << std::endl; // output 2
    std::cout << (*defaultset.begin())[0] << std::endl; // output 1

    return 0;
}
```

Here `OppositeVectorComp` define a new order on vectors where

```
OppositeVectorComp(a,b) true iff a <b is false
```

By using the type `std::set<std::vector<int>, OppositeVectorComp>` we define a set which use the custom std::less.